# Flume takes time to upload a file to HDFS

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, flume, flume-ng, bigdata

I need to get your assistance with regard to checking why does flume take time to upload flatfiles to HDFS. I tried uploading just 1 file (10MB size) however, 17 hours has past it's still uploading with ".tmp". When I checked the Log Details, it seems like it's stuck in the Channel:

> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-1
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-2
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-3
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-4
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-5
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-6
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-7
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-8
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFile    CheckpointBackupCompleted
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-9
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-10
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-11
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-12
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-13
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-14
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-15
>
> Nov 10, X:XX:XX.XXX PM    INFO    org.apache.flume.channel.file.LogFile               Closing RandomReader /data5/flumedata/log-16

Here is the configuration:

```
agent.sources = source1
agent.channels = channel1
agent.sinks = sinks1

agent.sources.source1.type = spooldir
agent.sources.source1.spoolDir = /data1/forupload
agent.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent.sources.source1.basenameHeader = true


agent.channels.channel1.type = file
agent.channels.channel1.capacity = 1000000
agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent.channels.channel1.checkpointDir = /data5/checkpoint
agent.channels.channel1.dataDirs = /data5/flumedata
agent.channels.channel1.useDualCheckpoints = true
agent.channels.channel1.backupCheckpointDir = /data5/backupcheckpoint
agent.channels.channel1.maxFileSize = 900000000

agent.sinks.sinks1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.sinks1.hdfs.path = /user/flume
agent.sinks.sinks1.hdfs.filetype = DataStream
agent.sinks.sinks1.channel = channel1
agent.sinks.sinks1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
agent.sinks.sinks1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .csv
agent.sinks.sinks1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent.sinks.sinks1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent.sinks.sinks1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
```

Appreciate your help with this

Answer (score 0):

I think all data has been sent. You can check if the file you want to send has been removed to `file.name.COMPLETED`. If it has been removed, the file should be already sent.

However, there might be some data that's still in the file channel, since data is transmitted in batch. If the size of data left is less than the batch size, it will be left in the channel.

In order to finish sending, you can use `kill -SIGTERM flume_process_id` to kill the process. When flume receives this signal, it flushes all data left to HDFS. And the file on HDFS will be renamed, i.e. remove the `.tmp` suffix.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am actually looking for options to efficiently use Flume without having someone to manually kill the process to fully upload all data to HDFS, eliminate long wait time and keep it as 1 file when uploaded (since as of right now, the file splits). Did I miss anything in the configuration?

Comment: @bertsnipe Flume moves streaming data from source to destination. It supposes that the data is endless. So when you put another file into the spool directory, Flume will send the new file to channel, and any data of the first file that's left, will be send to sink and hdfs. If you only want to send one file with Flume, you have to kill it manually. I'm also new to Flume, if you get a better solution, please correct me.

Comment: Also, your configuration of the HDFS sink forbids rolling file. So all data should be put into a single file on HDFS.